# Динамическое изменение типа std::vector

Tags: c++, vector

```
struct Datas
{
    std::string DataName;
    std::vector< > Data;
};
```

Как динамически менять тип у вектора в структуре в зависимости от типа записываемого значения, в него могут записываться значения следующего типа (int, double, string)

Comment: `std::variant`/`std::any`

Comment: А шаблон не подойдёт?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Используйте [std::variant](https://en.cppreference.com/w/cpp/utility/variant) (или, если ваш компилятор не поддерживает C++17, то boost::variant).

```
std::vector< std::variant< std::string , int, double > > Data;   // если хотите свой тип для каждого элемента
std::variant<  std::vector< std::string > ,
               std::vector< int > , 
               std::vector< double > > Data;   // если хотите массивы однотипных элементов.
```

Альтернативы: использовать union (стиль C), либо просто завести три переменных:

```
std::vector< std::string  > DataStr;   
std::vector< int          > DataInt;   
std::vector< double       > DataDbl;
```

Comment: ну студия с++ 17, поддерживает но компилировать не хочет, выдает такую вот ошибку `#error:  class template variant is only available with C++17`, в настройка проекта включил поддержку